# Current and easy to follow tutorial on developing PhoneGap apps with xcode

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I've been trying to get set up to develop a PhoneGap app using xCode. So far all the tutorial I've tried to work through either seem out of date or weren't very straight forward. [This one](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html) for example. Can anyone suggest a current straight forward tutorial that they have recently abd successfully gotten started from.

Comment: the link above is for 2.0.0, look 3.1.0 for latest!!!